# Tracking clicks on outbound links

Tags: tracking

I have a website based on wordpress. I want to implement a click tracking system on some of external links. Is there any method of doing so without using any external website or google analytic s.
**Can't i call some external php script to run when the link is clicked and keep incrementing a variable everytime.**
Please help . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can link to a script that tracks redirects and redirects the user.

```
<a href="./out.php?url=http://domain.com">outbound link</a>
```

*UPDATE:* Don't forget to redirect with the status 301 to preserve the PageRank value added to the linked site.

Comment: thanks so much for your help. can u also suggest how  in this external php script i keep updating the external variable?how do i use this global variable?

Comment: You can store the number of redirects to each URL in a database (MySQL, SQLite, CSV file, …). You get the target URL from $_GET['url'].